# How to find uncertain files using node js

Tags: node.js

In a folder, there are some files such as

```
'user1_time1.log',
'user1_time2.log',
'user1_time3.log',
'user1_time4.log',
'user2_time1.log',
'user3_time1.log',
'user4_time1.log'
```

How to find all the files like `user1_time*.log` in a nodeJS program?

Comment: You can use [`node-glob`](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob).

Comment: thank you very much , node-glod solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
const fs=require('fs');

let files;
fs.readdir(path,(err,list)=>{
   if (!err) {
     files=list.filter((name)=>name.substr(0,10)==='user1_time' && name.substr(-4)==='.log')
   }
})
```